# Acegi encode password in browser or server

Tags: security, spring-security, passwords, md5, encode

I'm doing with acegi security and i see in .xml file:

```
<property name="passwordEncoder">
     <bean class="org.acegisecurity.providers.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" />
</property>
```

but i don't now my password will be encode from browser or server ???

Comment: The password isn't encoded in the browser, only the server. You should read up on password hashing. Also, you definitely shouldn't be using Acegi as it is no longer developed and contains known vulnerabilities. You should try to upgrade your app to use Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like really old code (since it's still using the `org.acegisecurity` namespace) but the behavior is the same. The password sent from client (browser) to server is encoded with the given class before it's compared to the value stored in the datasource (which may or may not be a database).

Pointer 1: [excerpt](http://www.packtpub.com/article/spring-security-configuring-secure-passwords?utm_source=springsecuritybook.com&utm_medium=blog&utm_content=authorsite&utm_campaign=mdb_003541) from the excellent "Spring Security 3" book that covers this topic

Pointer 2: [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html)